# intercetpUrlMap causes Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)

Tags: grails, spring-security

Following problem: I have a grails-application running on a server and I want to restrict access to all the content by using **spring-security-plugin**.

So I created following interceptUrlMap:

```
interceptUrlMap = [
            '/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'],
        ]
```

But then a 'Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)' occurs. If I just secure some controllers, it works fine without any errors.

How can I avoid this error? (I need to secure the whole content, this includes also some generated files from my grails-app)

---

### Solved!

The failure was, that you had to be authenticated fully for the login page, so it was an endless loop.

After having a look at this [blogpost](http://groovyguts.wordpress.com/2010/02/01/excluding-the-login-page-from-grails-security/),

I changed my interceptUrlMap into following:

```
interceptUrlMap = [
            '/login/**' :['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
            '/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'],
        ]
```

Have a look at the blogpost (link above) if you have the same problem.

Greetings,
Beasty